# How to connect host only to network bridge with QEMU VMs on linux host

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge, qemu

I have a bridge working for qemu. I am able to start multiple copies of the same machine and they can network together. I am not interested in connecting to the outside internet. This is all on ubuntu 20.04. The guest systems are emulated arm64 running linux.

What I do need is for the VMs to connect to the host. My current understanding is that I need to create a tap device for the host and add it to the bridge. If the IP addresses are on the same subnet I should be able to ping between host and guests.

I use the "qemu-bridge-helper" to automatically create tapN devices on VM boot.

This is what I have so far that doesn't work:

```
sudo ip tuntap add name host0 mode tap
sudo ip addr add 169.254.246.10/24 dev host0
sudo ip link set host0 master br0
sudo ip link set host0 up
```

The iptables configuration (output of `iptables-save`):

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Jul 26 09:35:45 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [115122:42396994]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [122239:21074871]
COMMIT
```

I would be super grateful for anyone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please add the output of `iptables-save` in your question.

Comment: Use libvirt; it makes everything much easier.